# Colouring a table with pandas a exporting to excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, colors

I used panda to eliminate the < in the excel table and the values that have "<" I divide by two, por example "<0.12" would be 0.06. After that I want to color the cell  background in red.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgHHi.png)

I would like to have a table like this but in excel (without the id if possible)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mau6M.png)

This is the code I used to filter, eliminate < and divide by two (the table have more columns that I showed in the first image)

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
COLUMN_NAMES = ['reception_date', 'day', 'PM10', 'PM2,5', 'SO42--S', 'NO3-N', 'HNO3-N+NO3--N', 'NH3-N+NH4+-N']

class CellValue:
def __init__(self, input):
self.value = None
self.is_fixed = False
> #I eliminate < in certain cells and I divide by two the number.
try:
if isinstance(input, str):
if "<" in input:
value = input.replace('<', '')
value = value.replace(',', '.')

self.value = float(value)/2
self.is_fixed = True
else:
self.value = float(input)
self.is_fixed = False

return
except:
self.value = np.NaN
return

self.value = float(input)

def __format__(self, fmt):
return format(self.value, fmt)

Read excel.
df = pd.read_excel('data/PRODUCTS.xls', sheet_name='G', names=COLUMN_NAMES)

df = df.set_index('day')

df = df.query("not day.isnull()")
df = df[1:]
df['PM10'] = df['PM10'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['SO42--S'] = df['SO42--S'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['NO3-N'] = df['NO3-N'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
df['HNO3-N+NO3--N'] = df['HNO3-N+NO3--N'].apply(lambda x: CellValue(x))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please be mindful when posting code that indentation is important especially with Python. It can make it difficult for others to determine what/how your code executes when there is no indentation of the code sample.

Comment: Most likely you want to write the dataframe to Excel using Pandas `ExcelWriter` and `to_excel`. You can fill cells in Excel based whatever criteria either directly or by using Conditional formatting.